# How do I get the XY co-ordinates of current focus view?

Tags: android, view, focus, coordinates

I want to get the Real time (x,y) co-ordinates of currently focused view. I don't have much experience in android.I want to simulate focus based on input co-ordinates i.e. If I give input co-ordinates as (100,100) then wherever the focus is currently on screen it should go to the view in which the above co-ordinates fall. Please Help.

Comment: Kindly give reason for down voting

Comment: how do you what to do this? programmatically? or via your computer?

Comment: As I already mention I want to simulate(code/program) focus.i.e parse source co-ordinates to a function and move the focus in the view in which the source co-ordinate lies. Use case is navigation in Android TV menu.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Would love to know how to get the focus coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Rect rectf = new Rect();
<imageView>or<view>.getLocalVisibleRect(rectf);
```

to retrieve the bounds of a view.

Before this just loop over your views. I think it should work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2226706/1979882

or this

```
int location[] = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4692133/1979882

for global coordinates:

`v.getLocationOnScreen()` or `v.getLocationInWindow()`

Comment: Thanks Vyacheslav for the suggestions. I can get the bounds of view but it is with respect to the current view whereas I want the co-ordinates with respect to (0,0) (top left assumed) some base reference like in a graph paper. Can you help me out over this ?

Comment: I tried with the edit also. It gives static co-ordinates. Moreover, v.getLocationOnScreen() gives co-ordinates for touch events.  my question is for currently focus view.